# Why is incrementing a long long much slower than incrementing an int?

Tags: c++, integer

I was recently curious to see roughly how many integer increments C++ could handle in a second. To test this, I wrote a short driver program, which is shown below:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num = 0;
    while(++num) {
        if(num%100000000 == 0) { // prints num every 100 million iterations
            cout << num << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I compiled this code under g++ 7.5.0 with optimization -O3, the program managed to increment approximately 800,000,000 times a second.

But when I switched the type of the `int` to a `long long`, I found that the performance was severely degraded, to around 100,000,000 times a second.

Can someone explain why this difference occurs?

Comment: FWIW, measuring output is really not going to tell you anything.  If you're outputting to the screen, that's going to be your bottleneck.  If you want to know performance of different types, you should do some sort of arithmetic computations on them.

Comment: I doubt it's the incrementing that's taking longer rather than computing the modulus or even printing them to screen. But benchmarking at this level of granularity is notoriously difficult to disentangle.

Comment: try compiling in godbolt and look at generated asm.

Comment: If you benchmark CPU speed it would make sense to let everybody know which one. Also OS (32/64) could be handy. Btw most probably you do not benchmark increment speed but modulo operation.

Comment: @NathanPierson yes the modulus might be the bottleneck.  Instead of using `num%100000000` try `num&0x7ffffffL`, that should be much faster although not as convenient since it's not a power of 10.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Gotta be careful with that though; if you don't parenthesize it, the `==` happens first. :-)

Comment: @ShadowRanger you're right.  I don't get bitten by that often, but when I do it hurts.

Comment: How did you compute the speed? Did you take into account that in the `long long` case you are doing the square of the number of iterations of the `int` case?

Comment: @user207421 I presumed they were just watching the output and using a stopwatch.

Comment: @MarkRansom I'm asking the OP what he actually did. I'm not interested in anybody's presumptions. If that is what he did, he doesn't have a valid value for speed, only for time..

Comment: @user207421 there's a direct but inverse relation between speed and time.  And if they were measuring the time it took for the loop to complete, it would be a *lot* worse than 8 times slower.

Comment: @user207421 Yes, I did use a stopwatch to estimate the number of iterations that the program would complete in 1 second.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Signed division is accomplished with the `IDIV` instruction. Per [Agner Fog's instruction tables](https://agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf), on the Haswell architecture, the reciprocal throughput of `IDIV` for 32 bit registers is 8-11, while for 64 bit registers its 24-81. That is, it takes roughly between 2x and 10x longer to do 64 bit integer division when using 64 bit registers than it takes for 32 bit registers. The numbers vary by architecture, and have a wide range even for Haswell specifically, but an 8x loss in performance seems reasonable. It's not the increment (`INC` has fixed and absurdly fast speed; it can be dispatched four times per clock cycle apparently), it's your test to limit the amount of output you're performing that uses `% 100000000` with larger operand sizes.

Perhaps try replacing it with masking to print based on a large power of 2 instead of a power of 10 (`AND` is ridiculously cheap and not tied to register size), e.g:

```
if((num & ((1 << 27) - 1)) == 0)
```

If you really like using powers of ten, you could always spring for an upgrade to IceLake; looks like there the difference is only reciprocal throughput of 6 vs. 10, so the performance loss would be less than 2x.

Comment: Another way to isolate out the division might be to use two different variables, one `int` for determining the output cycle (and reset it to 0 when you output so you don't need division), then one for timing the increment of `long long`.

Comment: @MarkRansom: True. Or just an outer loop wrapping an inner, where the outer prints once per loop, and the inner never prints and runs some fixed number of times or whatever. Basically anything that gets rid of division (which is so much more expensive than increments that it swamps what you're trying to observe) in favor of something low/fixed cost so you're not measuring your own timing overhead more than what you're timing.